# Where are the new collectibles in 1.05 located?

Tags: the-last-of-us

I had all collectibles, comics, and firefly pendants collected and got all the related achievements and tags. For some time, my collectibles page said 141/141 collected. After update 1.05, it now reads 141/145. I just played through the single-player campaign again and didn't find anything new. **Where are these 4 new collectibles located?**

Comment: I can't confirm for sure, but as the individual chapter breakdowns add up to 141, it's believed that the additional four will come from the upcoming single player DLC.